# High score returns to 0

Tags: android

Please help me, code below

The `textview` is always 0 when i close and start my app.

**EDIT**

The full code is now added.

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);

int mynum1 = ea1.TimeCounter++;
int mynum2 = ea2.TimeCounter++;
int mynum3 = ea3.TimeCounter++;
int mynum4 = ea4.TimeCounter++;
int mynum5 = ea5.TimeCounter++;
int mynum6 = ea6.TimeCounter++;

in = (mynum1) + (mynum2) + (mynum3) + (mynum4) + (mynum5) + (mynum6) ;
txt.setText(Integer.toString(in));
TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView26);
SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
String ss = sps.getString("Score", "Nothing Found");
tt.setText(ss);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);

        TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        if (Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()) < Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString())) {

            String current = txt.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("Score", in);
            editor.commit();
            tt.setText(current);

        }
        else if(Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString())) {
            SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            String ss = sps.getString("Score", "Nothing Found");
            tt.setText(ss);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Any type of exception you got?

Comment: use Integer.parseInt() function & when you open the app and want some value in TextView then load that value into the TextView in onCreateMethod from the sharedpreferences.

Comment: With reference to your other question. you should save value of `TimeCounter` in the shared preference.

Comment: Also replace `Integer.valueOf()` with `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: i am not able to fetch the variable for TimeCounter

Comment: @Rohit5k2 please help me

Comment: @Devam03: you are no where using that variable. Please post your full code of activities. Because one variable is being used in 3 activities its difficult to point out the problem.

Comment: what i say is that timecounter method is not the problem. It would be the same thing. actually it is. both will give same output. i need solution for that "0" thing.

Comment: what I think that 'in' value is always zero....printOut the value of variable 'in'.....change ea1.TimeCounter++  TO ++ea1.TimeCounter .I hope you will get some different value

Comment: i have got the variable by :          String current = Integer.toString(in);

Comment: I really appreciate everyones help. I have got my answer. I am posting as my answer.  Thanks once again

Comment: Answer posted. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now i got an answer

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);

            int mynum1 = ea1.TimeCounter++;
            int mynum2 = ea2.TimeCounter++;
            int mynum3 = ea3.TimeCounter++;
            int mynum4 = ea4.TimeCounter++;
            int mynum5 = ea5.TimeCounter++;
            int mynum6 = ea6.TimeCounter++;

            in = (mynum1) + (mynum2) + (mynum3) + (mynum4) + (mynum5) + (mynum6) ;
            txt.setText(Integer.toString(in));

            TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView26);
            SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            String ss = sps.getString("Score", "0");
            tt.setText(ss);

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);

                    TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView26);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString())) {

                        String current = Integer.toString(in);
                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                        editor.putString("Score", current);
                        editor.commit();
                        tt.setText(current);

                    }

                    else if(Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()) < Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString())) {

                        SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
                        String ss = sps.getString("Score", "Nothing Found");
                        tt.setText(ss);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```